Pseudo-inverse of the product of three matrices
Let $D$ a $n\times n$ diagonal matrix not full rank (e.g. with some zeros on the main diagonal) and let $B$ a $n\times n$ symmetric matrix not full rank. I would like to express the pseudo inverse of the product $(DBD)^-$ as the product of the pseudo inverses.

Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about how to ask a good question.

This should be possible, but the pseudo-inverses will all be of different types
